How to change font position of coefficient in corrplot
I need some help please to change the font position of the coefficients displaying in my correlation visualisation using corrplot package in R Studio.
My code (detailed below) is working well, it adds the coefficient and also p-value asterisks to my correlation plot, but unfortunately the coefficient and asterisk in each block appear on top of each other. It would be great if I could find a way to change the position of the coefficient text or the asterisks, so that the asterisks appear above each of the coefficients? Thanks in advance!
corrplot(C_corr, p.mat = testRes$p, type = 'lower', addCoef.col = 'grey50', number.cex = 0.75, order = 'hclust', tl.col = 'black', tl.cex = 0.8,
         cl.ratio = 0.2, tl.srt = 45, col = COL2('PuOr', 10),
         sig.level = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05), pch.cex = 0.9,
         insig = 'label_sig', pch.col = 'grey20')


Note I have found this thread that has a workaround I can use, but I thought I would check here in case this function has been automated now and someone knows how to do it (the thread is 3 years old now): Changing the position of the signifigance pch symbols in `corrplot()`?
Cheers
